# No module named 'pyrebase' in heroku python app

Tags: django, python-3.x, firebase

I'm trying to upload my django website to heroku platform but i got error:
**no module named pyrebase**

I'm trying to connect my django app with firebase API wrapper which "pyrebase". Everything is wroking well locally but when i upload it to my app on heroku it show me that message and when tried to see what is really inside python3.6/site-packages there was no such package. By the way, i'm already using requirement.txt in my project directory to install a 3rd party as packages in python and also pyrebase 3.* is included in this file but when i navigatei got that error!. Is there is a way i can install pyrebase to site-package directory in heroku python app?

You can check it by yourself here:   https://thegate1.herokuapp.com

[image: The packages inside site-package directory]

The results of my requirements.txt:

```
CacheControl==0.12.5
cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cycler==0.10.0
dill==0.2.8.2
Django==1.11.12
enum34==1.1.6
firebase-admin==2.12.0
Flask==1.0
functools32==3.2.3.post2
future==0.16.0
futures==3.2.0
gax-google-logging-v2==0.8.3
gax-google-pubsub-v1==0.8.3
gcloud==0.17.0
gnuplot-py==1.8
google-api-core==1.3.0
google-auth==1.5.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0
google-cloud-storage==1.10.0
google-gax==0.16.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
grpc-google-logging-v2==0.8.1
grpc-google-pubsub-v1==0.8.1
grpcio==1.14.0
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.7
impacket==0.9.11
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jws==0.1.3
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==2.0.2
msgpack==0.5.6
nltk==3.3
numpy==1.13.3
oauth2client==3.0.0
pcapy==0.10.5
pipenv==2018.7.1
ply==3.8
protobuf==3.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycryptodome==3.4.3
pyparsing==2.2.0
pyreadline==2.1
Pyrebase==3.0.27
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-gflags==3.1.1
python-jwt==2.0.1
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.11.1
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
rethinkdb==2.3.0.post6
rsa==3.4.2
scapy===git-archive.devc1696e497
six==1.*
tabulate==0.8.1
terminaltables==3.1.0
urllib3==1.23
virtualenv==16.0.0
virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you added `pyrebase` to your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Yes it is already included as Pyrebase==3.*

Comment: Check it throgh server's terminal also

Comment: run `heroku run pip freeze` and add those result to question

Comment: Ok i will put the results of requirement.txt in the question itself

Comment: do NOT run your site online in debug mode!!!

Comment: nothing more...?

Comment: @hansTheFranz Why?! and how to run and deploy??

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I added it to my question, now can you take a quick look about them and tell me what is the missing thing?